# bootstrap 5 svg font icons not working properly

Tags: svg, icons

I have problem bootstrap 5 some svg web font icons not working

```
<i class="bi bi-check-square-fill"></i>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have set the ``path`` **stroke** color to black. Open F12 tools and hunt the CSS you applied to see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I put this query, then the stable version of bootstrap 5 was not available, then this problem was coming.
All the icons are working since Bootstrap is stable and updated

Comment: When this problem occurred, the Bootstrap icons appeared newly arrived. when after new update all icons were correct

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to add bootstrap-icons.min.css to

```
<head>
<link href="bootstrap-icons-1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

2. then you can use this two ways seamless

1. `<i class="bi bi-facebook"></i>`
2. `<img alt="Bootstrap" src="bootstrap-icons-1.10.5/graph-up.svg">`